# Is there a fibration sequence of spectra $K\mathbb{F}_q\to KU\to KU$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-k-theory, loop-spaces

Quillen famously constructed a fibration sequence $BGL(\mathbb{F}_q)^+ \to BU \to BU$ to compute the algebraic K-groups of finite fields, where the second map is $\psi^\ell-1$ for $\ell$ a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_q^\times$. Does this lift to the level of the K-theory spectra?

I don't know much about delooping, but I would guess that if we had a fibration sequence $BGL(\mathbb{F}_q)^+ \to BU\times \mathbb{Z} \to BU\times \mathbb{Z}$ of $E_\infty$-spaces, this would then deloop to a fibration sequence of the associated connective $\Omega$-spectra. However, this seems out of reach, since Quillen's method proceeds via the Atiyah-Segal completion theorem and only produces a homotopy class of map.

Comment: As far as I know, such a fiber sequence of spectra (with $ku$ in place of $KU$ for obvious connectivity reasons), exists only when you $l$-complete where $l$ is a prime different from $p$. In fact I'm not even sure the Brauer lift is a map of H-spaces if you do not complete away from the characteristic

Comment: is there a reference where this is all written down?

Comment: First, as Denis said, you need connective K-theory. If you're fine with p-completion (where p is different from char(F_q)), then there is a fiber sequence L_K(1) K(F_q) -> KU_p -> KU_p. So you'd need to show that the p-completion of K(F_q) is the connective cover of its K(1)-localization. This seems to be true, just by inspection. I don't know if there is an integral version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The infinite loop space/spectrum level statements were written down in

May, Quinn, Ray, Tornehave:
"$E_\infty$ Ring Spaces and $E_\infty$ Ring Spectra" (1977) [http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/e_infty.pdf](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/e_infty.pdf) ,

see Theorem VIII.3.2 and its proof on pages 224-225.  For a prime $p$ and a prime power $r=q$ generating the $p$-adic units (take $r=3$ for $p=2$), May writes $j^\delta_p$ for $K(\mathbb{F}_r)$ completed at $p$, viewed as a discrete model for the connective complex image-of-$J$ spectrum, and argues that this spectrum is equivalent to the homotopy fiber $F\psi^r$ of $\psi^r-1 \colon kU \to bu$, after $p$-completion.  Here $kU = ku$ is the connective complex $K$-theory spectrum and $bu$ is its $1$-connected cover.  See also Section 19 of the survey paper

May: "Infinite Loop Space Theory" (1977)
http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/18.pdf ,

which may be easier to read.

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful! is there any way to see how the brauer lift fails to be good enough before completion? (e.g. fails to even be a map of h-spaces, as denis said?)